# Multi-dimensional array search for part of word or phrase and remove key

Tags: php, arrays, json, search

Before I start, I am learning and I am not going to claim to be a PHP expert. I've tried several different things but this method has gotten me closest to what I am looking for.

I have a JSON array that I am looking to search through and if part of the text matches any part of a line (Alerts) in the array, remove the whole key from the array. (If possible, I just want this to match the latest key and not remove all keys that have a match)

The code below is working on the latest item in the array but can't search an older record.

For example,

```
[8] => Array
       (
           [Code] => 9
           [Alerts] => bob went away
       )

   [9] => Array
       (
           [Code] => 9
           [Alerts] => randy jumped in the air
       )

)
```

If I call the script, with the term of 'bob' it will find nothing. If I call the script with the term 'randy' it will work perfectly deleting key 9. I can then search for a term of 'bob' and it will remove key 8.

Here is what I have so far. (Again there might be a better way)

```
<?php   
$jsondata = file_get_contents('myfile.json');
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$done = 'term';
$pattern = preg_quote($done, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $value)
    $contents = $value['Alerts'];
{
    if(preg_match($pattern, $contents, $matches))
    {
        $trial = implode($matches);
    }
    if ($contents == $trial)
    {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach ($arr_index as $i)
{
    unset($json[$i]);
}
$json = array_values($json);
file_put_contents('myfile-test.json', json_encode($json));
echo $trial; //What did our search come up with?
die;
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to get it to work by using the following if anyone ever needs it. It's a little more simple than I was originally going about it. This will stop on the first key of found text. To remove all records, simply remove the "break" and it will remove all keys containing said text or phrase.

```
$pattern = preg_quote($done, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $contents) 
{
    if(preg_match($pattern, $contents['Alerts'], $matches)) {
      unset($json[$key]);
      break; 
   }
}
$json = array_values($json);

file_put_contents('myfile-test.json', json_encode($json));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code that uses `$contents` is not inside the `foreach` loop. The loop just has one statement in its body:

```
$contents = $value['Alerts'];
```

When the loop ends, `$contents` contains the last alert value, and then that's used in the code block after it.

You need to put that statement inside the braces.

```
<?php   
$jsondata = file_get_contents('myfile.json');
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$done = 'term';
$pattern = preg_quote($done, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
$arr_index = array();
foreach ($json as $key => $value)
{
    $contents = $value['Alerts'];
    if(preg_match($pattern, $contents, $matches))
    {
        $trial = implode($matches);
    }
    if ($contents == $trial)
    {
        $arr_index[] = $key;
    }
}
foreach ($arr_index as $i)
{
    unset($json[$i]);
}
$json = array_values($json);
file_put_contents('myfile-test.json', json_encode($json));
echo $trial; //What did our search come up with?
die;
}
```

You should use your editor's feature to automatically indent code, it will make problems like this more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the input Barmar. I actually originally had it setup as such but the problem is it will then change the array to only the one found for some reason. I actually simplified it a bit and it is working as intended. Thanks much for your help!

Comment: What's the point of `$trial = implode($matches);`? There are no capture groups in `$pattern`, so `$matches` just has one element. That should just be `$trial = $matches[0];`

Comment: You're overwriting `$trial` each time through the loop, so when you `echo $trial` at the end it will just be the last one that was found. Maybe you should make an array of them.

Comment: Yes - You're correct. That was simply for my quick troubleshooting to see if it was picking up anything. Ultimately, it isn't needed at all in the new code. Thanks again! I really appreciate it!